# Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources while reading and inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

normally it works fine (it recalculates time to time production based on daily meter readings , the problem starts when other apps are inserting data into [dbo].[MeterReading] ( at least I belive this is the source of deadlocks), what would you reccomend to avoid exceptions ?

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    declare @ResultVar float;

    DECLARE @Val1 TABLE 
    (   
        RowID INT    IDENTITY ( 1 , 1 ),
        InputId int,
        TimeStampUtc1 smalldatetime,
        Val1 float
    );
    DECLARE @Val2 TABLE 
    (   
        RowID INT    IDENTITY ( 1 , 1 ),
        InputId int,
        TimeStampUtc2 smalldatetime,
        Val2 float
    );
        
        
    WITH CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT [Val],m.InverterInputId, m.[TimeStampUtc]
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.InverterInputId ORDER BY m.[TimeStampUtc] DESC) AS RN
            FROM [dbo].[MeterReading] AS m
            inner join InverterInput AS ii on m.InverterInputId = ii.InverterInputId
            inner join Inverter      AS i  on ii.InverterId     = i.InverterId 
            where ii.InputName = 'TotalYield' and i.PlantId = @plantId and  m.[TimeStampUtc] >= @from and m.[TimeStampUtc] <= @to
    ) 
    INSERT INTO @Val1 (Val1,InputId,TimeStampUtc1 ) Select [Val],[InverterInputId],[TimeStampUtc] FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1;
        
    WITH CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT [Val],m.InverterInputId, m.[TimeStampUtc]
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.InverterInputId ORDER BY m.[TimeStampUtc] ASC) AS RN
            FROM [dbo].[MeterReading] AS m
            inner join InverterInput AS ii on m.InverterInputId = ii.InverterInputId
            inner join Inverter      AS i  on ii.InverterId     = i.InverterId 
            where ii.InputName = 'TotalYield' and i.PlantId = @plantId and  m.[TimeStampUtc] >= @from and m.[TimeStampUtc] <= @to
    ) 
    INSERT INTO @Val2 (Val2,InputId,TimeStampUtc2) Select [Val],[InverterInputId],[TimeStampUtc] FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1;
        
    --select Val1 , Val2, Val1-Val2 as Result, [@Val1].InputId,[@Val1].TimeStampUtc1,[@Val2].TimeStampUtc2  from @Val1
    select Sum(Val1-Val2) as Result from @Val1
    inner join @Val2 on [@Val1].InputId = [@Val2].InputId

    

END
```

Comment: its the CTE the same besides the ASC vs DESC...do you need temp tables at all for this?...why not just return one query directly from the tables without the temps

Comment: @Ctznkane525 ok will try to modify this, but how about adding with(nolock) when inserting as quick fix ?

Comment: NO NO NO - don't throw random functions or hints into a query without understanding the problem you are attempting to solve and how the function / hint works. Don't splatter code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). And why do you need identity columns in your table variables when you never use them?

Comment: Are the columns InverterInputId and inverterID indexed columns? This will make the joins happen a lot faster and less likely to run into other transactions.

Comment: This whole script is complete overkill for the problem. Looks like `FIRS_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` would work well here. If you want help on the deadlock, you need to provide us with the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` definitions, the deadlock graph, and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan